# warning: enumeration value 'MAX_RANKS' not handled in switch

Tags: c++11, sublimetext3

getting error in sublimetext that Max_ranks isn't handled even though it is defined?  Also sublimetext won't let user continue playing Blackjack after the initial build. For example when I build the game, it shows "the dealer is showing 6. You have: 15. (h) to hit or (s) to stand".  But when i press h or s nothing happens..

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <ctime> // for time()
#include <cstdlib> // for rand() and srand()

enum CardSuit
{
    SUIT_CLUB,
    SUIT_DIAMOND,
    SUIT_HEART,
    SUIT_SPADE,
    MAX_SUITS
};

enum CardRank
{
    RANK_2,
    RANK_3,
    RANK_4,
    RANK_5,
    RANK_6,
    RANK_7,
    RANK_8,
    RANK_9,
    RANK_10,
    RANK_JACK,
    RANK_QUEEN,
    RANK_KING,
    RANK_ACE,
    MAX_RANKS
};

struct Card
{
    CardRank rank;
    CardSuit suit;
};

void printCard(const Card &card)
{
    switch (card.rank)
    {
        case RANK_2:        std::cout << '2'; break;
        case RANK_3:        std::cout << '3'; break;
        case RANK_4:        std::cout << '4'; break;
        case RANK_5:        std::cout << '5'; break;
        case RANK_6:        std::cout << '6'; break;
        case RANK_7:        std::cout << '7'; break;
        case RANK_8:        std::cout << '8'; break;
        case RANK_9:        std::cout << '9'; break;
        case RANK_10:       std::cout << 'T'; break;
        case RANK_JACK:     std::cout << 'J'; break;
        case RANK_QUEEN:    std::cout << 'Q'; break;
        case RANK_KING:     std::cout << 'K'; break;
        case RANK_ACE:      std::cout << 'A'; break;
    }

    switch (card.suit)
    {
        case SUIT_CLUB:     std::cout << 'C'; break;
        case SUIT_DIAMOND:  std::cout << 'D'; break;
        case SUIT_HEART:    std::cout << 'H'; break;
        case SUIT_SPADE:    std::cout << 'S'; break;
    }
}

void printDeck(const std::array<Card, 52> &deck)
{
    for (const auto &card : deck)
    {
        printCard(card);
        std::cout << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}

void swapCard(Card &a, Card &b)
{
    Card temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

// Generate a random number between min and max (inclusive)
// Assumes srand() has already been called
int getRandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    static const double fraction = 1.0 / (static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX) + 1.0);  // static used for efficiency, so we only calculate this value once
    // evenly distribute the random number across our range
    return static_cast<int>(rand() * fraction * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

void shuffleDeck(std::array<Card, 52> &deck)
{
    // Step through each card in the deck
    for (int index = 0; index < 52; ++index)
    {
        // Pick a random card, any card
        int swapIndex = getRandomNumber(0, 51);
        // Swap it with the current card
        swapCard(deck[index], deck[swapIndex]);
    }
}

int getCardValue(const Card &card)
{
    switch (card.rank)
    {
    case RANK_2:        return 2;
    case RANK_3:        return 3;
    case RANK_4:        return 4;
    case RANK_5:        return 5;
    case RANK_6:        return 6;
    case RANK_7:        return 7;
    case RANK_8:        return 8;
    case RANK_9:        return 9;
    case RANK_10:       return 10;
    case RANK_JACK:     return 10;
    case RANK_QUEEN:    return 10;
    case RANK_KING:     return 10;
    case RANK_ACE:      return 11;
    }

    return 0;
}

char getPlayerChoice()
{
    std::cout << "(h) to hit, or (s) to stand: ";
    char choice;
    do
    {
        std::cin >> choice;
    } while (choice != 'h' && choice != 's');

    return choice;
}

bool playBlackjack(const std::array<Card, 52> &deck)
{
    // Set up the initial game state
    const Card *cardPtr = &deck[0];

    int playerTotal = 0;
    int dealerTotal = 0;

    // Deal the dealer one card
    dealerTotal += getCardValue(*cardPtr++);
    std::cout << "The dealer is showing: " << dealerTotal << '\n';

    // Deal the player two cards
    playerTotal += getCardValue(*cardPtr++);
    playerTotal += getCardValue(*cardPtr++);

    // Player goes first
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "You have: " << playerTotal << '\n';

        // See if the player has busted
        if (playerTotal > 21)
            return false;

        char choice = getPlayerChoice();
        if (choice == 's')
            break;

        playerTotal += getCardValue(*cardPtr++);
    }

    // If player hasn't busted, dealer goes until he has at least 17 points
    while (dealerTotal < 17)
    {
        dealerTotal += getCardValue(*cardPtr++);
        std::cout << "The dealer now has: " << dealerTotal << '\n';
    }

    // If dealer busted, player wins
    if (dealerTotal > 21)
        return true;

    return (playerTotal > dealerTotal);
}

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); // set initial seed value to system clock
    rand(); // If using Visual Studio, discard first random value

    std::array<Card, 52> deck;

    // We could initialize each card individually, but that would be a pain.  Let's use a loop.
    int card = 0;
    for (int suit = 0; suit < MAX_SUITS; ++suit)
    for (int rank = 0; rank < MAX_RANKS; ++rank)
    {
        deck[card].suit = static_cast<CardSuit>(suit);
        deck[card].rank = static_cast<CardRank>(rank);
        ++card;
    }

    shuffleDeck(deck);

    if (playBlackjack(deck))
        std::cout << "You win!\n";
    else
        std::cout << "You lose!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler can't know you'll never pass `MAX_RANKS` to the switch, you should add a `default` case if you want to handle that.

Comment: To answer the second part of your question: Don't run it from sublime if you need it to take input; sublime does not gather input from the output window and pass it back to the program that's running.

Comment: so I need to run it in Code::blocks or Xcode or some IDE? would rather not as these C++ IDEs are so clunky to use..sublime is very clean and easy

Comment: what is the process to run the file in the command line terminal? I have cd into the directory and ran cl cfile.cpp but terminal is not running it

Comment: @Bryn `cl` is the Microsoft C Compiler. You mention XCode, are you on OS X? If so, there is no `cl` on your system...

Comment: yes using osX so was wondering how to run/compile c++ file on terminal

Answer (score 1):

As is very normal, you should add a `case default:` to your `switch` statement. Even if you leave it blank, it'll make the compiler happy.

I recommend being kind to the next reader of your code (maybe you!) and leave a comment about *why* it's an empty case.

Run it from the command-line to test it. Sublime is a text editor, not an IDE.

Comment: how do you run a .cpp in command-line? I cd into the directory where the file is saved but when I run cl CTextbook.cpp  the command line states cl is not defined?

Comment: I don't know which compiler you're using.

Comment: I know that. You have to compile it before you can run it.

Comment: oh thanks..my question was how do I compile by .cpp file form Sublime to run it in terminal? thats the step that is giving the error

Comment: No, your question was "Why is the compiler warning me about an unhandled case"